# How to repeat a range vertically using formula in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a google spreadsheet which I'm building as a template. Copies of the template will be made for multiple groups, so any formula/formatting needs to carry over. I have an issue which I thought was simple enough but after scouring for days I haven't come across a solution that's worked for this scenario. I want to take the relevant text and have the format repeat every time there's a value in a corresponding column.

I have a growing list of Test Words in Column A. I have managed to make each individual Test Word repeat three times vertically into Column B. There's also a set of three Values per Test Word in Column C. So columns A and B currently look like this (Please ignore the "- - -" I don't know how else to format it so it looks like two separate columns):

Test Word1 - - - Value 1 
Test Word1 - - - Value 2 
Test Word1 - - - Value 3

I need this to auto-populate every time a new Test Word is added:

+Test +Word1 - - - Value1 
Test Word1 - - - - - Value2 
Test Word1 - - - - - Value3 
+Test +Word2 - - - Value1 
Test Word2 - - - - - Value2 
Test Word2 - - - - - Value3 
+Test +Word3 - - - Value1 
Test Word3 - - - - - Value2 
Test Word3 - - - - - Value3

I've tried different variations of arrayformula, transpose/split/rept. That's not to say those types of formula won't work, just that they haven't with the particular ways I've tried. If it helps, I've laid it out in [a viewable sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LZxIrVRt0-XYfNhJQnWj1Waq5JOs3hiyzsgiPGq5AOA/edit?usp=sharing).

Any help is SUPER appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new at this, but I may have part of the answer.  If you use this formula in column D on row 3 (and fill down), it will create the output you seem to want, as shown in column E:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),3)=0,  
   "+" & SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(A$3:A,QUOTIENT(ROW(C3),3),1)," "," +"), 
   INDEX(A$3:A,QUOTIENT(ROW(C3),3),1))
```

I've added this in a new tab, Sheet1-GK in your spreadsheet.

This handles your test words.  I'm not sure where you are getting the three value words that have to be matched with each test word.  If they are kept somewhere else, they could be found using a VLOOKUP.  Let me know if you need more help.

Are the three values the same for each different test word?
You show "Value1", "Value2", and "Value3" beside all of the test words.  I assume that those could really be different, like "Value9", or "Value97" or whatever?

These formulas do need to be copied down the whole column.  It is likely that this could be done with an ARRAYFORMULA using VLOOKUP.  I could try to get that working, if that is important to you.